# Broken For Loop when Training CNN

Tags: python, for-loop, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I've built a relatively deep layered CNN which takes in 224x224 images. I have a trainset of ~5000 images which I'm using to train my CNN using the conventional for-loop method. However, I have an issue where the loop only prints the outcome of the first epoch and then just continues the run (i.e. the cell stays *Executing* forever).

My code with output:

```
#Model training

epochs = 2

for epoch in range(epochs):

    running_loss = 0

    #Train
    cnn.train()

    for images, labels in trainloader:
        if cuda:
            images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)

        optimiser.zero_grad()
        outputs = cnn(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        running_loss += loss.item() * images.size(0)
        loss.backward()
        optimiser.step()
    
    epochs_train_loss = running_loss / len(trainloader.dataset)
    print ("Epoch {}, Training Loss: {}".format(epoch, epochs_train_loss))
```

Output:

```
Epoch 0, Training Loss: 0.3014729377767928
```

Comment: Have you not posted this question already?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why you don't see an output for the next epochs, is that the inner training loop:

```
for images, labels in trainloader:
        if cuda:
            images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)

        optimiser.zero_grad()
        outputs = cnn(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        running_loss += loss.item() * images.size(0)
        loss.backward()
        optimiser.step()
```

Gets stuck, or stalls after the epoch 0. You could check this by putting a print statement, after the `optimiser.step()` statement.

These things can be bothersome. Good luck with it!